# Android: Message keys gets changed for signed apk in Firebase real time database chat

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed a chat application with a firebase real-time database in android, it stores all the messages in the firebase real-time database, and it is working perfectly fine in debug mode however when I create a signed build it automatically changes all my messages key into a,b,c,d and so on.

For example, I have stored a message with keys "name", "message", "image" etc, Message gets stored perfectly fine with these keys in debug mode however in release mode all these keys are changed into a,b,c etc.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: It might be caused by proguard. Try minifyEnabled false in your gradle and see if the problem still appears.

Comment: @MarkWalczak Thank you so much for your response! could you please let me know what do I need to do to prevent this?

Comment: @MarkWalczak sure! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proguard obfuscates the code that you've written in your app. It changes the class names, variable names, function names in your code to avoid decompilation of your app. So, whenever you write your model classes in Firebase, the ones which you're referring to, you can omit this classes from obfuscation using proguard.

To do that, follow the few steps mentioned below.

1. Go to `app/proguard-rules.pro` directory and open the `proguard-rules.pro` file.
2. Add the following few lines to that file

> -keep class com.yourpackage.model.DataModel{ public private *;}

Above line will keep the class DataModel from obfuscating by Proguard. You have to give correct path of your class in that field.

Also, don't forget to annotate variables in your Model classes like below:

```
@SerializedName("yourKeyName") 
private int yourKey;
```

Those "yourKeyName" will be used to serialize and deserialize the objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!! I have implemented your answer but the problem still persists.

Comment: did you give correct path to your model class in front of -keep class?

Comment: yes, I copied the package given on the top of the class and added class name with .ClassName.

Comment: Did you add it in correct proguard-rules.pro file? Because there is a different proguard-rules for every library you add through app/libs

Comment: I have added it in app/proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: All I can say right now is, it should work 100% as I've been using it in my app for quite some time now. Did you annotate your variables as I said?